# set variable value from if condition angular (Ionic 3)

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm trying to set a value from a condition inside a `subscribe()`. Here is what I'm doing at the moment

```
var statuscode;
      this.http.post('http://192.168.3.223:84/fppb/andro_login',this.loginData)
        .subscribe(
                function(response) { 
                    console.log(response);
                    if(response)
                        statuscode = '1';
                    else
                        statuscode = '2';
                },
                function(error) { 
                        statuscode = '3';
                }
        );
        loader.dismiss();
        console.log(statuscode);
```

This code always gives me `undefined` inside my `console.log(statuscode);`;

In addition to that, this page : `http://192.168.3.223:84/fppb/andro_login` is returning true or false. Here is the code which determines the response:

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            echo json_encode(true);
        }else{
            echo json_encode(false);
        }
```

How can I fix this ?

Sorry for my poor english, and thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

So, I want to show the `alert` for the specified `statuscode`. When doing this:

```
  signIn(){
    let loader = this.ld.create({ content: "Please wait..." });
    loader.present();

        var headers = {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'POST'

            };

        let bodyString = JSON.stringify(this.loginData); // Stringify payload

        var statuscode;
          this.http.post('http://192.168.3.223:84/fppb/andro_login',this.loginData)
            .subscribe(
                    function(response) { 
                        console.log(response);
                        if(response)
                        {
                                let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                                    title: 'Sukses',
                                    subTitle: 'Login Berhasil',
                                    buttons: ['OK']
                                });
                                loader.dismiss();
                                alert.present();
                        }   
                        else {
                            let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                                title: 'Gagal',
                                subTitle: 'Username atau Password salah',
                                buttons: ['OK']
                            });
                            loader.dismiss();
                            alert.present();
                        }
                    },
                    function(error) { 
                            let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                            title: 'Gagal',
                            subTitle: 'Username atau Password salah',
                            buttons: ['OK']
                        });
                                loader.dismiss();
                                alert.present();                        
                    }
            );
    }
```

I get this error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since javascript is asynchronous, before the observable subscribe to an event the console log statement executes. That is why it prints undefined.

You need to move the statement inside the `subscribe`

```
   .subscribe(
            function(response) { 
                console.log(response);
                if(response)
                    statuscode = '1';
                else
                    statuscode = '2';

                console.log(statuscode);
            },
            function(error) { 
                    statuscode = '3';
            }
    );
    loader.dismiss();
```

Comment: i do that because there is something i need to do, i want to `alert.present();` for specified statuscode.

Comment: why can't u do it inside subscribe]

Comment: initialize the `alertCtrl` variable